# How to Delete Dynamic Memory allocated in Class Constructor using destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to deallocate the memory of an object using destructor. this memory was allocated on the declaration of the object. the code snippet below is a comprehensive version of the program I'm making, but it explains my problem.
I know that the problem is coming in deallocation via destructor but I have no clues what might be cause of the exception.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class student 
{
private:
    char const* firstname;
    char const* lastname;
public:
    student()
    {
        firstname = new char[10];
        lastname = new char[10];
        firstname = "HelloMaria";
        lastname = "Something";
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "Firstname =  " << firstname<<endl;
        cout << "Last name = " << lastname << endl;
    }
    ~student()
    {
        cout << "Destructor Called" << endl;
        delete[] firstname;
        delete[] lastname;
    }
};
int main()
{
    student obj1;
    obj1.print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Please note that in default constructor of class student,  lastname="Something"
I've mistakenly wrote it as "SomethingVe", 
the exception problem still continues even if its Something instead of SomethingVe.

Comment: a breakpoint is triggered when destructor is called and program crashes

Comment: `firstname = "HelloMaria";` changes `firstname` to point at a string literal instead of the array you allocated.  You're allocating char arrays, but then overwriting the pointers to them... you leak memory and can't free them later.  Also, they're not big enough anyway (you need enough space for the terminating null).

Comment: `firstname = new char[10];` allocates 10 bytes of memory. `firstname = "HelloMaria";` overwrites that pointer and leaks the memory you just allocated. When the destructor is called you try to `delete` memory that was never allocated with `new`. Use `strcpy` to copy a string into the allocated memory and be careful that you allocate enough space for all of the characters plus one extra for the terminating 0. 10 is not enough for "HelloMaria", it must be at least 11.

Comment: @RetiredNinja gotta change the pointers too. `strcpy` won't like a `char const*` targets, which apparently the OP shoved in there to squelch the warning saving literal addresses to those members.

Comment: note that `"HelloMaria"` occupies 11 char array, not 10 char array. trailing zero needs its place to live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
    firstname = new char[10];
    lastname = new char[10];
    firstname = "HelloMaria";
    lastname = "SomethingVe";
```

First you set both `firstname` and `lastname` to point to newly allocated `char` arrays, which is fine... but then you immediately change them to point to statically-allocated strings instead.  That means that when you pass the pointers to `delete[]` in your destructor, you are trying to delete strings you never allocated, which invokes undefined behavior.

The proper way to handle strings would be to use `std::string` instead of allocating your own char-buffers, but if you can't do that for some reason, then the next-best way to do what you are trying to do would be more like this:

```
student()
{
    firstname = alloc_string_buffer("HelloMaria");
    lastname = alloc_string_buffer("SomethingVe");
}

private:
   // Helper function to allocate the right-sized char-buffer and 
   // copy the bytes from the passed-in literal string into the buffer
   char * alloc_string_buffer(const char * s)
   {
       size_t numBytesToAllocate = strlen(s)+1;  // +1 for the NUL terminator byte
       char * buf = new char[numBytesToAllocate];
       strcpy(buf, s);
       return buf;
   }
```